# How to find gradient of multiple variables at a given point?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, gradient

I need to find gradient of function (x**2+y) at point [2, 4].

```
import numdifftools as nd
import sympy as sym
from sympy import *

x, y = sym.symbols('x y')

def rosen(x, y): 
    return (x**2 + y)
grad = nd.Gradient(rosen)([2, 4])
print("Gradient of is ", grad)
```

```
TypeError: rosen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: Check your parentheses here `grad = nd.Gradient(rosen)([2, 4])`, they look to be incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument to function passed to `nd.Gradient` must be an array.

```py
import numdifftools as nd

def rosen(xy): 
    return (xy[0]**2 + xy[1])

grad = nd.Gradient(rosen)([2, 4])
print("Gradient of is ", grad)
```